# Rewire a ceiling fan, ceiling fan on, not controllable by switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

Friends with electrical background could use some help. The top drawing was the original of how the electrical ran in my wall. The thing I messed up and did was not take a picture of the switch before I dismantled it. There was a jumper in the switch box, connecting what wires I don't know. This switch would only control the ceiling fan in our kitchen.

I went to rewire it, which is the new drawing, bottom version and now, the switch for the fan doesn't work, ceiling fan stays on unless you pull chains, and the switch now controls a switch box in my dining room for an outlet and the outside lights. Any idea which wires the jumper would have been for, I think that's all I need to right this ship. Or maybe it's more than that

Sorry, was hoping to post a picture. Original wall wiring was w/b from attic to outlet, w/b from outlet to switch, red, white and black out of switch to fan. Now, in the junction box in my attic, I have the original w/b from the outlet coming in to my junction box, connected to the w/b going to switch, then the w/b coming from switch to the red, white and black, connecting the black and red going to the fan with the black coming from the switch, and the whites connected together as well. My ceiling fan stays on, but not controlled by my switch. Instead, my switch controls another switch box in my dining room. I feel my mess up was not taking a picture of the original switch box, and that the jumper is the key to fixing this problem. I have some childish diagrams I drew and was hoping to be and to post those, but it doesn't seem like that's possible.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, what if, I just wanted the switch to control all power to the unit as a whole, and that when I turn the switch on, that turns the light on, and allows me to control the fan and light by pull chain??

Comment: I assume that 3 wire cable is for the ceiling fan. Red and Black is to power the fan and lights. You could use a switch for each one or twist them together and use a single switch. Which appears to be what you did in your lower drawing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a hot-neutral reversal somewhere. You don't show it, but I'm going to assume that you have a ground wire in there somewhere. If you have a multimeter, the voltage between white and ground should be 0 (or almost 0, a couple of volts at most). If not, then you need to take apart all of the connections in the circuit and test each one to figure out where the reversal was introduced and fix it.

Comment: So, i have all the ground wires twisted together and grounded to the screw in the junction box, is that wrong? Same thing with my switch. I have them twisted together and connected to the ground screw on the switch.

Comment: Your ground wires sound OK. Measuring the voltage between the white wire and ground is simply a diagnostic. Also, the voltage between the black wire and ground should be 120 volts.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that when I get home! Thank you! I'll report back.

Comment: At the switch, using my volt meter, between the black and white its 122, between the black and ground is nothing.

Comment: Between the ground and white nothing.

Comment: Ok...hopefully this will help out immensely, Update...I've recreated the the box..looks like the segment of wire that has the black, white and red, red and black were connected to the switch, then the remaining whites and blacks were wire nutted and a jumper was used. http://m.imgur.com/a/6AAlV

Comment: I don't see any ground wires. Do you have any grounds?

Comment: The original wiring, no.

Comment: I don't understand how your drawing relates to the picture of your switch wires. What is the box in the bottom of your drawing? Is that a different junction box? What was in that junction box before you disconnected everything? A switch? An outlet? If an outlet, was there a switch somewhere that controlled that outlet?